# Find the dependent row of a 4x4 matrix with rank 3.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Consider the matrix
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&-1\\0&1&-1&1\\0&0&-1/3&0\\0&1&0&1\end{pmatrix}
$$

I think this matrix has rank 3.

But I cannot identify the row which depends on the other three rows.

Comment: Isn't this obvious? Take $3$ times the third row! Then it is $(0,0,-1,0)$.

Comment: I don't think you can do that in general.  If you have a set of non-linearly independent rows then you can generate some of those rows from a linear combination of the others.  There isn't a unique independent row.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Not so obvious, what if you multiplied the second row by 1/3?  It seems like the OP was asking for which row in particular, not a combination?

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome Why should I do this? It is so much easier to multiply it by $3$. Yes, obviuosly the *second row* is just the sum of the new third row and the last. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Foreword** There is no need to use Gauß elimination, but let's do it to see why the rank is three, in another way.

Multiply by $-3$ the third row, and you get
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now use Gauß elimination doing row $4$ minus row $2$, substituting into row $4$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now it's rather clear that the last two rows are equal, hence the rank is three.

You can see the dependence by reading Gauß elimination backwards, that is:
$$\text{row}~3 = \text{row}~ 4 - \text{row} ~ 2$$

**Remark**

If you don't want to use all this process, you can go to the start and see the dependence as

$$\text{row} ~ 3 = -\frac{1}{3}\left(\text{row} ~ 4 - \text{row} ~ 2\right)$$

Comment: Perhaps easier is to multiply the third row by $3$ and then the second row is just the sum of the new third and the original fourth row. That's all. No matrices necessary, no Gauss elimination necessary.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, I wanted to illustrate a general (slow) way. The OP seems not to find it that "obvious". Better to be clear than fast.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it is clear, so nothing against your solution. Just wanted to say, you don't need another Gaus elimination. That may confuse the OP.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Mmm Perhaps you're right, I will write it in the answer!